# Flatten JSON nested data in bigquery to table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table in bigquery with one of its column with JSON document. I would like to flatten that column to a separate table with all the json fields as separate columns. JSON doc has 'dataset' array and a sub array as 'hearratezone' as below

```
{
    "activity": “running”,
    "dataset": [
        {
            "time": {
                "_seconds": 1651
                            },
            "value": {
                "customHeartRateZones": [],
                "heartRate": [
                    {
                        "max": 92,
                        "min": 30,
                        "name": "Normal"
                    },
                    {
                        "max": 128,
                        "min": 92,
                        "name": "Fat Burn"
                    }
                                    ]
            }
        }
    ],
}
```

I want table to look like this with each heartratezone array elements to be created as separate row with corresponding other json repeated values. Please suggest how it can be done in SQL query.

```
activity time   v_customheartrate v_heartrate_max.      v_heartrate_min v_heartrate_name
running  1651   null              92                    30              Normal
running  1651   null              128                   92              Fat Burn
```

Thanks
Ash

I have tried UNNEST and cross join but not able to get desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT '''
  -- put your json string here.
  ''' AS json
)
SELECT JSON_VALUE(json, '$.activity') activity,
       JSON_VALUE(d, '$.time._seconds') time,
       v_customheartrate,
       JSON_VALUE(hr, '$.max') v_heartrate_max,
       JSON_VALUE(hr, '$.min') v_heartrate_min,
       JSON_VALUE(hr, '$.name') v_heartrate_name,
  FROM sample_table 
  LEFT JOIN UNNEST(JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(json, '$.dataset')) d
  LEFT JOIN UNNEST(JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(JSON_QUERY(d, '$.value.customHeartRateZones'))) v_customheartrate
  LEFT JOIN UNNEST(JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(JSON_QUERY(d, '$.value.heartRate'))) hr
```

**Query results**

[image]

- assumes that `value.customHeartRateZones` is an array of string.

Comment: Thanks very much, this works for me and now I understand the logic :)